# write classes in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Having lots of experience in Java, i am new to ios and swift and looking for directions.

In java i use to create DataObjects (like Point,person etc...) every one in different class file (*.java)

```
public class GamePreferences
{
int gameId;
int developerId;
String orientation;
}
```

In Swift i see many examples where classes are being written inside the View Controller

Is it really how it should be done? or should i create different files for this purpose? if yes what is the file types suited for defining classes?

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it's primarily opinion-based. There is no real answer to this and it largely depends on the context of what you're doing. This is the same as in C++ or even Java with _inner classes_ where multiple classes can be defined within the same file.

Comment: @nburk ok, but my question is why all the examples i see all the work is being done in the view controller that is why its weird to me. further more what files do i use in swift as class files and how do i import them to classe for me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing every class in a different `.swift` file is better way.

I prefer to write many classes in the same file only if the class is ridiculously small or  related only to one class that is the main class in the file.

The advantages of every class in a different files are,

- Easier to navigate and improve readability
- Great granularity when working with version controls.Wspecially those where you have a locking checkout mechanism for editing files
- Easier for new developers to find the appropriate classes

> how do i import them to classe for me to use?

in Swift, you don't need to import classes. Simply use it. Only you need to import your external modules (targets), if any.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen people create enums and structures inside the `UIViewConroller` class but never entire classes inside this.

You definitely should create separate classes, hopefully in separate files. It's not a limitation of the system.

Answer (score 1):

In most examples, you see classes in the same file as the ViewController because it's easier to scroll through.
In a real life context, it depends on your preferences and/or project norms.
I prefer to split it in different files but it's totally up to you.